# Wordpress permalinks on IIS?

Tags: wordpress, iis-7

I am using WordPress on Windows 7 IIS to develop. I am uploading images in WordPress for a blog post. The image displays fine on the web site but as soon as I enable permalinks the images no longer work and any future images uploaded I get back an error:

```
HTTP Error 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

I am not sure why this would be happening, here is my `web.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
          <match url="*" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

As soon as I turn off my permalinks and use the default it works, does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Thanks very much this helped me! was looking everywhere for url rewrite issue

Answer (score 13):

> The image issue was a permission issue, but simply setting it manually
>   on the original image file or parent folder is inadequate.  The
>   behavior of WordPress is that it writes the original file using IUSR
>   to a temporary system directory that is defined in the PHP.ini file. 
>   This temp folder does not have IIS_IUSRS permissions on it, so when
>   windows moves this file from the temp folder to the application's
>   upload folder, its final home, IIS_IUSRS only has read permissions, so
>   the permissions are not inherited from the file's parent folder.
>
> To fix this, there are two solutions.
>
> 1. Change the permissions on the temp folder giving IIS_IUSRS write/modify.
> 2. Change the path of the temp folder in the PHP.ini file to a folder that does have IIS_IUSRS write/modify permission.
>
> Here is a good source detailing the problem: 
>   http://www.howyoudo.info/index.php/how-to-fix-windows-server-upload-file-inherit-permissions-error/
>
> I chose to move the temp folder in my PHP.ini to
>   C:\inetpub\temp\uploads and also give it permissions. After uploading
>   an image in wp-admin, I was able to access the image (original, not
>   resized) from a browser wihout the 500.50 error.

[From source](http://forums.iis.net/t/1159252.aspx)

Comment: doesn't fix files already uploaded but the C:\inetpub\temp\uploads trick worked great. Be sure to set the correct permissions on inetpub\temp\uploads. All new Media Library uploads no longer get the 500.50 after changing php.ini and restarting web server.

Answer (score 1):

There's a slightly different web.config at [Using Permalinks « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite) as well as other options for Permalinks without mod rewrite on Windows.

Comment: Hi songdogtech, thanks for the link. That was the docs I've been following, I retried and still no luck :/ Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it. Turns out IIS didn't have permissions, i followed this: http://www.tech-problems.com/http-error-500-50-url-rewrite-module-error-wordpress-images/ and it worked just fine!

Comment: I think that the WordPress codex is wrong. The `web.config` that @JeffTaggarty has worked for me but the WordPress one doesn't. It also disagrees with the [IIS.net documentation](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13365927)

Comment: @RobertColumbia; true, but: that's a 6 year-old answer, and, that's a link to a WordPress Codex page, which will redirected when/if the URL changes. If you look at links in the other answers, you will see much more potential for link rot.

Answer (score 1):

To help other users this issue is due to permissions in IIS and a fix is also here:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1159252.aspx

Answer (score 1):

use this below mention RULEs in your web.config file ..

```
  <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false"/>
        <action type="None"/>
    </rule>

    <rule name="Redirect Image to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|js)$" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}"/>
    </rule>

    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="." ignoreCase="false"/>
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php"/>
    </rule>
```