# How to set up url rewrite in iis for WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, url-rewriting

how do I set the rewrite url in IIS to load my page without index.php? E.g. https://blog.sunamo.cz/2021/12/25/s/ is 404 but https://blog.sunamo.cz/index.php/2021/12/25/s/ is 200.

It no longer appears in the settings:

[image: Permalinks settings]

Lex Li: Unfortunately no. It seems IIS don't use rewrite rules. I have added:

```
<rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="*.php" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="401" statusReason="Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials" statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
</rule>
```

test in IIS will match url https://blog.sunamo.cz/index.php, not https://blog.sunamo.cz/index.ph but https://blog.sunamo.cz/index.php is still loading without 401.

The same, if I'm using any snippet from stackoverflow etc., which could help, it have no effect.

Thanks everybody

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL Rewrite IIS and Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51057533/url-rewrite-iis-and-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It was because app pool was not 32bit. Just one change, recycle and works like a charm!